# Cognos group that contains other group

Tags: cognos

I need to extract cognos group from content store and their parent. I've found the query but It doesn't work if a group contains other group. I've tried with MotioPi but it doesn't show the information that i need

Samuele

My query:

```
with RecursiveCTE
as(
SELECT 
          cmobjnames.cmid as object_id,
          cmobjnames.name objnames,
          CAST(cmobjnames.name AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS TreePath,
          cmobjects.PCMID as parent_id          
   FROM   cmobjnames           
          INNER JOIN cmobjects
                     ON cmobjnames.cmid = cmobjects.cmid
        where cmobjnames.cmid=104 -- id membro padre directory Cognos
        and cmobjnames.ISDEFAULT=1
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 
          cmobjnames.cmid as object_id,
           cmobjnames.name objnames,
           CAST(H.TreePath + '\'
         + CAST(cmobjnames.name AS VARCHAR(100)) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) as TreePath,
           cmobjects.PCMID as parent_id          
   FROM   cmobjnames           
          INNER JOIN cmobjects
                     ON cmobjnames.cmid = cmobjects.cmid
          INNER JOIN RecursiveCTE H
          ON H.object_id =cmobjects.PCMID
        where  cmobjects.classid IN ( 54,8,26) -- seleziono folder , gruppi, ruoli
        and cmobjnames.ISDEFAULT=1
)       
 SELECT objnames as Name
 , object_id
 , parent_id 
 , TreePath
FROM RecursiveCTE
INNER JOIN cmobjects
 ON object_id = cmobjects.cmid
 where cmobjects.classid IN ( 54,26) -- seleziono  gruppi, ruoli
```

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:**

Hacking away at the Content Store database is neither supported nor recommended.  Neither IBM nor I will help you if something goes wrong.  Use this information at your own risk.

**Assumptions:**

- You are asking about Cognos groups, not security groups in an external directory provider (like Active Directory).
- You are using SQL Server.

---

"Parent" is not the right word.  Role and group membership is recorded through object relationships defined in CMREFORD1.

```sql
with
objname as (
  select o.CMID
  , coalesce(n2.name, n.NAME) as 'NAME'
  from CMOBJECTS o
    left outer join CMOBJNAMES n on n.CMID = o.CMID
                           and n.LOCALEID = 92
    left outer join CMOBJNAMES n2 on n2.CMID = o.CMID
                           and n2.LOCALEID = 118
)

select MemberName.NAME as 'Member'
, GroupName.NAME as 'Group'

from         CMOBJECTS MemberObject
  inner join objname MemberName on MemberName.CMID = MemberObject.CMID
  inner join CMCLASSES MemberClass on MemberClass.CLASSID = MemberObject.CLASSID
  inner join CMREFORD1 r on r.REFCMID = MemberObject.CMID
  inner join CMOBJECTS GroupObject on GroupObject.CMID = r.CMID
  inner join objname GroupName on GroupName.CMID = GroupObject.CMID

where MemberClass.NAME = 'group'
  and MemberName.NAME = 'All Authenticated Users'
```